# How to save and load moves in a game using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I'm very sorry if something here is not explained properly.
I had made a game of tic tac toe using javascript, with html of course.
I had a problem when I wanted to add two buttons, one of save and the other of load.
I want to save only the last game played and send it to save.
I was able to save the game but when I want to reload it it is not loaded for me.
Any options for an idea or help please?
I can't use intermediate javascript,we haven't gotten there yet.
Here is my javascript code.
The game has been built in HTML table.
It also has an undo button, a restart button and a button to show the game won in the fewest moves.
If you have any tips for improving the code I would love to, and if you have any recommendations for changing things I would love to too!

```js
const arrMem=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];        //Saving the history of movement,the index is the location
const arrFlag=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];      //Put only one img in a cell
const arrX=['','','','','','','','',''];
const arrO=['','','','','','','','',''];
const arrXO=['','','','','','','','',''];
var loc=1;
var td0=document.getElementById('td0');
var td1=document.getElementById('td1');
var td2=document.getElementById('td2');
var td3=document.getElementById('td3');
var td4=document.getElementById('td4');
var td5=document.getElementById('td5');
var td6=document.getElementById('td6');
var td7=document.getElementById('td7');
var td8=document.getElementById('td8');


//Creates an image and puts the image of the 'O' sign
function putSignO(x){
    var imgElement=document.createElement('img');
    imgElement.id=`${x}`;
    imgElement.src='/images/o_sign.png';
    imgElement.alt='undefined';
    var tdElement=document.getElementById(`td${x}`);
    tdElement.value='O';
    tdElement.append(imgElement);
}

//Creates an image and puts the image of the 'X' sign
function putSignX(x){
        var imgElement=document.createElement('img');
        imgElement.id=`${x}`;
        imgElement.src='/images/x_sign.png';
        imgElement.alt='undefined';
        var tdElement=document.getElementById(`td${x}`);
        tdElement.value='X';
        tdElement.append(imgElement);
}

//puts image in the pressed area,and chagne the turn to the other player.

var turn=1;
function putSignTd(tdCell){
    if(turn===1){
        if(arrFlag[tdCell]===0){
            arrMem[tdCell]=loc;
            arrX[tdCell]='X';
            loc++;
            putSignX(tdCell);
            turn=0;
        }
        arrFlag[tdCell]=1;
    }else{
        if(arrFlag[tdCell]===0){
            arrMem[tdCell]=loc;
            arrO[tdCell]='O';
            loc++;
            putSignO(tdCell);
            turn=1;
        }
        arrFlag[tdCell]=1;
    } 

}

//winFlag for if someone won the game or it's a tie game,checkIfWon checks the ways to win and alert if someone won or if it's a tie game.  

var winFlag=0;
function checkIfWon(){
    if(td0.value==='X'&&td1.value==='X'&&td2.value==='X'){
       alert("Player X Won!");
       winFlag=1;
    }else if(td0.value==='X'&&td3.value==='X'&&td6.value==='X'){
        alert("Player X Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td0.value==='X'&&td4.value==='X'&&td8.value==='X'){
        alert("Player X Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td1.value==='X'&&td4.value==='X'&&td7.value==='X'){
        alert("Player X Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td2.value==='X'&&td5.value==='X'&&td8.value==='X'){
        alert("Player X Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td2.value==='X'&&td4.value==='X'&&td6.value==='X'){
        alert("Player X Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td3.value==='X'&&td4.value==='X'&&td5.value==='X'){
        alert("Player X Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td6.value==='X'&&td7.value==='X'&&td8.value==='X'){
        alert("Player X Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td0.value==='O'&&td3.value==='O'&&td6.value==='O'){
        alert("Player O Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td0.value==='O'&&td4.value==='O'&&td8.value==='O'){
        alert("Player O Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td1.value==='O'&&td4.value==='O'&&td7.value==='O'){
        alert("Player O Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td2.value==='O'&&td5.value==='O'&&td8.value==='O'){
        alert("Player O Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td2.value==='O'&&td4.value==='O'&&td6.value==='O'){
        alert("Player O Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td3.value==='O'&&td4.value==='O'&&td5.value==='O'){
        alert("Player O Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(td6.value==='O'&&td7.value==='O'&&td8.value==='O'){
        alert("Player O Won!");
        winFlag=1;
    }else if(winFlag===0&&sumArr(arrFlag)===9){
        alert("It's a Draw!");
    }

    if(winFlag===1){
        for(let i=0;i<arrFlag.length;i++){
            arrFlag[i]=1;
        }
    }
}


// Sum arr numbers

function sumArr(arr){                         
    var sum=0;
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        sum+=arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}


function undo(){
    var maxVal=parseInt(Math.max(...arrMem));
    var maxIndex=arrMem.indexOf(maxVal,0);
    arrMem[maxIndex]=0;
    var tdEl=document.getElementById(`td${maxIndex}`);
    tdEl.value='';
    tdEl.innerHTML=''; 
    arrFlag[maxIndex]=0;
    if(turn===1){
        turn=0
    }else if(turn===0){
        turn=1;
    }
    winFlag=0; 
}



//Reset the game
function resetGame(){
    for(let i=0;i<9;i++){
        var tdEl=document.getElementById(`td${i}`);
        tdEl.value='';
        tdEl.innerHTML='';
        arrFlag[i]=0;
        arrXO[i]='';
        arrX[i]='';
        arrO[i]='';
    }
    winFlag=0;
    turn=1;

}

var highScore=10;
function gameScore(){
    var winRec=0;
    for(let i=0;i<arrFlag.length;i++){
        if(arrFlag[i]===1&&winFlag===1){
            winRec++;
        }
    }
    return winRec;  
}

function showRecord(){
    if(gameScore()<highScore){
        highScore=gameScore();
    }
    alert("The record is "+ highScore);
    
}

function saveGame(){
    var arrSaveX=arrX;
    var arrSaveO=arrO;
    for(let i=0;i<9;i++){
        arrXO[i]=arrSaveX[i]+arrSaveO[i];
        console.log(arrXO)
    }
    return arrXO;
}

function loadGame(){
    var arrLoad=saveGame();
    for(let i=0;i<9;i++){
        console.log(arrLoad[i]);
        if(arrLoad[i]==='X'){
            turn=1;
            putSignTd(i);
            arrFlag[i]=1;
        }else if(arrLoad[i]==='O'){
            turn=0;
            putSignTd(i);
            arrFlag[i]=1;
        }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Suggest creating a new test project where you can test a very basic save and load feature without all the game logic. Once you have your test project working as expected, then adapt that to your existing code.

Comment: what is arrLoad? It looks like you are initializing it but not doing anything with it

Comment: ya i forgot to write there saveGame() because i wanted to get the arr that returned from saveGame()

Comment: It seems like it keeps the last game clicked saved, as I wish, but when I click on Restart it erases all the memory of the saved game.